# p:fileDownload to be executed at the end

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need the PropertyActionListener to set the correct variable for the prepDownloadBalanceteII method (this method creates a PDF file). After that, I want to download the PDF.

What I am currently getting is the property being set correctly, but the file being downloaded before the prepDownloadBalanceteII method is called.

```
 <p:commandLink id="downloadBalancete" value="Balancete" ajax="false" action="#{reportsController.prepDownloadBalanceteII}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{object}" target="#{reportsController.accountingPeriod}" />
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{reportsController.download}" />
                        </p:commandLink>
```

Anyway I can make it work here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The action method is triggered after the download logic is executed. Use the actionListener instead of action in your commandlink. The actionListener will prepare the file stream for the p:fileDownload.

Comment: actionListener will fire before the f:setPorpertyActionListener, no?

Comment: I've fixed it by changing the method in the bean, by the way.